# Why is psutil CPU usage too low?

Tags: python, performance, psutil

I have written a performance monitor function in Python using `psutil` to measure CPU, GPU, and Disk I/O for benchmarking another application.  It worked great in my initial tests, but I found that it significantly under-reports CPU usage when it's near 100%.  I'm looking for help figuring out why this happens.

This function may seem over-complicated, but I'm trying to do two things:  Display the current usage in real-time; and also report the highest 5-second rolling average at the end.  This is because I can't predict how long the subprocess will take, and I want to smooth out short term fluctuations.

A simplified verion of the function is below.  In this example I've removed all the GPU and Disk measurement and changed the print statements a little for debugging.  Although I'm trying to sample once per second, I see the `elapsed` time fluctuates as high as 1.8 sometimes when CPU usage is very high.

This is running on Windows 10.  Task Manager shows constant 100% CPU usage with no fluctuation, and if I run `psutil.cpu_times_percent()` in another window that also shows 100%, while my function here is showing about 90%.

```
import psutil
import time
import shlex
import subprocess
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def perf_monitor(proc):
    # measure CPU, GPU, and Disk R/W every 1 seconds, and calculate a rolling average every 5 seconds
    # return the maximum of each rolling average
    rolling_interval = 5
    sample_interval = 1
    rolling_samples = []
    stats = {
        'cpu': 0,
    }
    cpu_count = psutil.cpu_count()

    while True: # loop until subprocess is finished
        # reset starting values
        start = time.time()
        cpu1 = psutil.cpu_times()
        cpu1 = cpu1.user + cpu1.system

        # measure again after the interval
        time.sleep(sample_interval)
        cpu2 = psutil.cpu_times()
        cpu2 = cpu2.user + cpu2.system
        
        # list starts at zero and counts up, then remains at 5
        elapsed = time.time() - start # may be slightly longer than sample_interval
        rolling_samples.append({
            'cpu': (cpu2 - cpu1) / cpu_count / elapsed,
        })
        # skip reporting for the first 5 seconds warm up
        if len(rolling_samples) < rolling_interval:
            continue
        
        # get the rolling average over a defined interval (5 seconds)
        rolling_avg_cpu = sum([sample['cpu'] for sample in rolling_samples]) / rolling_interval

        print([sample['cpu'] for sample in rolling_samples], elapsed) # for debugging
        print(f"CPU: {rolling_avg_cpu:.1%}  ", end='\n',)

        # update each stat only if it has increased
        if rolling_avg_cpu > stats['cpu']:
            stats['cpu'] = rolling_avg_cpu
        
        # remove oldest sample so we always keep 5
        del rolling_samples[0]

        # return stats when render is finished
        if proc.poll() is not None:
            return stats

if __name__ == "__main__":
    command = '"MyApp.exe'
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command))
        thread = executor.submit(perf_monitor, proc)
        stats = thread.result()
    
    print(stats)
```

Comment: You're having psutil roll up monotonically increasing values into averages, and operating on those averages. __Don't.__ The underlying OS interface chose monotonic values for a reason: They're much easier to calculate with without losing accuracy.

Comment: Example: You have high-resolution per-second samples, but you want a 5-minute average? You get a much more accurate result if you stored the individual values for total-CPU-cycles-used at the beginning of the end of the 5 minutes and _only compare those two values_, instead of taking a bunch of jittery 1-second averages and trying to come up with a 5-minute average from them.

Comment: ...so, in general: This is a place where using high-level abstractions is a losing proposition. Learn what's under the hood, and use it as-designed.

Comment: I'm getting 5-second averages, not 5 minute.  This would be easy if I only sample every 5 seconds.  It got complicated because I want to update the display every second.  (Actually I prefer to sample every 0.5 seconds)

Comment: Right, but my point is that if you don't roll things up at all, you can calculate averages between any points at which you have a (absolute-time, total-cpu-seconds-ever-used) tuple after the fact, without needing to look at any other points or even care that they exist.

Comment: So the magic that psutil is doing for you, changing the values it collects into averages? You don't want that magic. Stop using it.